# Yii2 gridview how to get related model only once for more attributes

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, lazy-loading

I have a Yii2 gridview. Now if I want to show related data using lazy loading it seems like this:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'relatedName',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return (($rel = $model->getRelated()->one()) ?
            $rel->name : '')
    ;}
],
```

If I want to show an additional attribute of the same related model, I can add a new attribute like above, but then Yii will be selecting the same related model once again for each row of data.
Without eager loading (unfortunately is not possible in this case) is it possible to force yii to select related only once for each row and make `$rel` reusable in many columns? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$model->getRelated()` returns ActiveQuery object. If you want to load a related model once you can do it with using `$model->related` instead of `$model->getRelated()->one()`. For example:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'relatedName',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return is_null($model->related) ? '' : $model->related->name;
    }
],
```

Or more simple way

```
[
    'attribute' => 'related.name',
],
```